# Using Emacs to find and copy relevant database records

Tags: search, copy-paste, programming, script

[I have reduced](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75023/automated-trim-of-28-million-text-records) a large text file to a 1.9GB size that Microsoft Access can handle, but only as a linked file. To permit full Access operations - to import the relevant data into Access - I need to extract, from that file, only the potentially relevant records.

[It has been suggested](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1820070) that the extraction process may have to be done by hand (i.e., through the use of code that proceeds line-by-line). I am wondering whether Emacs could provide a solution. This thought arises from the belief that I could have scripted WordPerfect for DOS to do it, back when I knew how to do that - though I suspect WP would gag on a 1.9GB file.

Each line in the 1.9GB file contains three tab-delimited fields. Example:

```
03d32aab-6041-49e8-8fc7-8af091b005d5    Seek Text A3    11
ee8029d3-7f4a-4132-8fda-12c5327a47e9    Seek Text A1    11
```

The list of items to extract consists of sorted data matching field 2. Example:

```
Seek Text A2
Seek Text A3
```

In that example, Emacs would look for an occurrence of "Seek Text A2" in the 1.9GB file, but would not find it. But it would find "Seek Text A3," and would therefore copy the relevant line (i.e., "03d32aab-6041-49e8-8fc7-8af091b005d5  Seek Text A3 11") to a separate file - which, at the end, would be small enough to import into Access.

I realize this could be slow in Emacs. I welcome suggestions for a faster way. But I don't mind letting the machine spend a day at it, if there is a reasonable Emacs solution.

I think my relevant Emacs skill only ever extended to simple macro recording (i.e., remember what I type). This instance seems to call for if-then logic. When I search for guidance in that, I find myself looking at material on Lisp programming. At present, that's a bit over my head.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `awk` or `perl` to me...

Comment: ... except that (I'm guessing) the OP is running on Windows and might not have these tools installed, although they are available e.g. through [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I can run Linux commands, but unfortunately I don't know awk or perl. I do tell myself that someday I should learn Python. Can't do that today, though. Memory says that Emacs can be a Swiss knife type of tool for my purposes, even if it doesn't always provide the most economical solution. But if it can't be done in Emacs, then I guess that's my answer.

Comment: How do you provide the sorted data? And how much sorted-data is it (order of magnitude of number of entries)?

Comment: If you confine yourself to using Emacs, then perhaps: make a copy of the file, then run a regex to replace all non-conforming lines with nowt. ?

Comment: Who needs MS Access when you can use **[SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065872/how-to-import-a-tsv-file-with-sqlite3)**?  Try importing the tsv file into an SQLite database as described in the previous link, and play with it.  I think it'll have no problem giving you the resultset you were looking for initially.

Comment: Of course Emacs can do anything you can do with any programming language, but it's not the appropriate tool for the kind of transformation you are envisioning here. Even if you don't know `awk` or `perl` or `python` or `sed` or any of these tools, you can learn the basics of some of them in a few hours with some reading and experimentation. Moreover, you can ask the question on the [Unix & Linux SE]() and chances are that somebody will oblige with a short awk script (or similar) or a command pipeline to do what you want. If you can run such things on your Windows box, you will be much happier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While, as others have pointed out, other tools might be more suitable for this job, it can certainly be done with Emacs. 1.9GB is not an unreasonably large file size for Emacs to handle on a somewhat modern computer.

## Using Emacs Lisp

There is a built-in command `copy-matching-lines` which takes you some of the way, but I believe the below custom command would be faster for your purposes:

```lisp
(defun my-copy-matching-lines (small-infile big-infile outfile)
  (interactive
   (list (read-file-name "Small file containing list of items to extract:\n")
         (read-file-name "Large text file:\n")
         (read-file-name "Output file:\n")))
  (save-excursion
    (find-file small-infile)
    (let ((match-strings (split-string
                          (string-trim
                           (buffer-substring-no-properties
                            (point-min) (point-max)))
                          "\n")))
      (while match-strings
        (let (line)
          (find-file big-infile)
          (goto-char (point-min))
           (when (search-forward
                 (concat "\t" (pop match-strings) "\t")
                 nil t)
            (setq line (buffer-substring-no-properties
                        (line-beginning-position)
                        (line-end-position)))
            (find-file outfile)
            (insert line "\n")))))
    (find-file outfile)
    (save-buffer)))

(call-interactively #'my-copy-matching-lines)
```

To use this, copy the code above into a file with an `.el` extension, like `mylisp.el` and open it in Emacs. You should now have a menu bar item called "Emacs-Lisp". Click it to reaveal a sub-menu with an entry called "Evaluate Buffer", which you should click. You will be asked for a file path/name three times:

1. The first time, navigate to the presumably smaller file containing the list of items to extract. On my system I now have to, confusingly, press save and confirm that I want to replace the file (it still works as expected otherwise).
2. The second time, navigate to the large 1.9GB file, and
3. the third time input a new file to save the output. (You might additionally have to confirm that you really want to open the 1.9GB large file.)

The code I shared makes some assumptions and might have to be adapted to fit your exact use case:

- It assumes that the list of items to extract contains one item per line, with "\n" as linebreak character, and should exactly match field two. A partial match would not return anything, since the field separators, which are assumed to be tabs `"\t"`, are included in the search string. You might want to remove the `"\t"`'s above to allow partial matches, or replace them with spaces `"   "` if the file doesn't contain actual tabs.
- It only returns the line of the first match per item, so if there are more matches these won't appear in the output file.

## Using keyboard macros

An alternative, if you want to avoid writing Emacs Lisp, is to record a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html). Type `M-x kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter` or `<f3>` to start recording a macro and `M-x kmacro-end-or-call-macro` or `<f4>` to stop. `M` stands for the meta key (and `C` for control).

Doing so will record a macro in the "Emacs command language". The macro given below will do almost the same thing as the Lisp code above (it doesn't loop), assuming you have the three files as described above open in Emacs, with names "insmall.tsv", "inbig.tsv", and "outfile.tsv", and that you are visiting the "insmall.tsv" file when calling the macro:

```
C-SPC                   ;; set-mark-command
C-e                     ;; move-end-of-line
s-c                     ;; ns-copy-including-secondary
C-a                     ;; move-beginning-of-line
C-x b                   ;; switch-to-buffer
inbig.tsv               ;; self-insert-command * 9
RET                     ;; newline
M-<                     ;; beginning-of-buffer
<<copy-matching-lines>> ;; copy-matching-lines
TAB                     ;; indent-for-tab-command
s-v                     ;; yank
TAB                     ;; indent-for-tab-command
RET                     ;; newline
C-x b                   ;; switch-to-buffer
outfile.tsv             ;; self-insert-command * 11
RET                     ;; newline
s-v                     ;; yank
C-x b                   ;; switch-to-buffer
insmall.tsv             ;; self-insert-command * 11
RET                     ;; newline
C-n                     ;; next-line
```

To use this you can record a macro replicating the above yourself (note that `<<copy-matching-lines>>` stands for `M-x copy-matching-lines`). Alternatively you can just record a shorter non-empty macro (so that there is something to edit), then call `M-x kmacro-edit-macro` or `C-x C-k RET`, paste the above macro, and press C-c C-c to finish. You can now call your macro `N` times by typing `C-u N M-x kmacro-end-or-call-macro` or `C-u N <f4>` when your cursor is on the line at which you want to start in "insmall.tsv".

Comment: Let me ask: I learned Emacs c. 1978. Wikipedia seems to say that Emacs Lisp emerged c. 1985. Did Emacs not have a simpler scripting tool before then - or, more to the point, is there not a simpler scripting tool for Emacs now? I'm hoping for a learn mode where it records my keystrokes in an editable list. I just took a look at a non-programmers introduction to Lisp in Emacs. First impression: I'd have to devote a week or more to get started.

Comment: There is indeed a way. I edited my answer in response. That said, I think the Lisp way would be faster and might work even if you don't know Lisp.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing my solution mainly for the comparison with AWK (see comments under NickD's answer), but also because it takes a slightly different approach than the solution by @orgtre:

This solution 'iterates' over the lines, and on each line checks for a match with any items in the sorted-data:

```lisp
(defun get-database-records (file sorted-data destination)
  (let ((target-buf (get-buffer-create "results"))
        (data (with-temp-buffer
                (insert-file-contents-literally sorted-data)
                (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t))))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents-literally file)
      (while (not (eobp))
        (let* ((line (thing-at-point 'line))
               (fields (split-string line "\t" t)))
          (when (member (cadr fields) data)
            (princ line target-buf)))
        (forward-line)))
    (with-current-buffer target-buf
      (write-file destination))))
```

I also benchmarked NickD's solution and compared it to my Emacs solution.
For that I ran both solutions on a file of 20 million (+ 2) lines (a file of 1.1GB).
AWK finished the job in 28 seconds vs Emacs in exactly 3 minutes (180 seconds).

Here I/we only used sorted data of 2 items. I guess when using a larger set of sorted data the (relative) difference becomes even larger.

So I guess NickD is totally right when he mentions that it makes more sense to ask this question on the right 'forum' (this is no criticism, just I think Nick is right).

Comment: Thanks for posting this - definitely useful! I think `member` does a linear search over the `data` argument whereas `awk`'s associative array uses a hashtable, so you are probably right that if you have lots of possible matches, it probably will be even slower,  although it's probably a wash for just a handful. But it is a reasonable elisp implementation of the `awk` algorithm. I would use `(nth 1 ...)` instead of `(cadr ...)` to select the second field just to make the correspondence closer although `nth` is 0-based, whereas the `awk` field numbering is 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

Using Emacs for this problem is just not a good way to go about it. You can learn enough about `awk` in a few hours to deal with such problems
and the advantage is a short program that runs relatively fast and can deal with large files, since it really only has to keep one line of the file in memory at any one time.

For example, here is a complete `awk` script to do what you want:

```awk
BEGIN { matchlist["Seek Text A2"] = ""; matchlist["Seek Text A3"] = ""; FS="\t"; }
      { if ($2 in matchlist) print $0; }
```

It consists of one line of initialization (remember all the matching patterns in the `matchlist` associative array and set the Field Separator to a TAB) and one line of processing which is implicitly applied to every line of the input file (see if field 2 is in the `matchlist` array and if it is, print the line). You run it like this:

```shell
awk -f script.awk -- input.txt
```

where `script.awk` contains the two-line script above and `input.txt` is your 1.9GB file. I duplicated your two-line input file a number of times to produce a 2GB file and then ran the above script: on my machine, it took 48 seconds to go through the whole file (and the output is half the input file's size: just the `A3` lines). How long would the macro in the answer above take to go through the whole file?

I hope you stop asking such questions here: since you can run these tools on your box, the appropriate place is the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) and the appropriate tool is `awk` (or perhaps `perl` or `python` or `sed` or some more specialized tool that already exists). Use the proper tool for the job.

Comment: While writing an answer, I also tested it on a 1.1 GB file. My solution and testing was very similar to your approach. Emacs did it in just over 3 minutes on my intel i5 from 2015. So it took 2 minutes longer (~4-5 for 1.9GB) , but it saved me from studying AWK. However, indeed this was only sorted-data with 2 items. So for larger sorted-data this quickly gets out of hand (although, I guess, we could keep it speedy for quite large sorted-date sets, by using clever hash-maps for the sorted-date), and AWK would be the right solution (actually, I just liked to share my Emacs 'benchmark' FYI :)

Comment: The point is that even if you don't know `awk`, asking the question in the right forum (Unix and Linux SE in this case) would likely produce the two-line script for you (or the OP) to try, without anybody batting an eyelid. Then once you see it, don't you *want* to learn enough `awk` to be able to do things like that quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Good point! I hope you still found the benchmark slightly interesting. I thought it was just fun to know/mention.

Comment: Did I miss something? All I see is your comment above, and I don't see a link in there, else I would have followed it. I also don't see a posted answer from you. Is there more information somewhere else?

Comment: I mean just the number 3 minutes on a 1.1 gb file in my comment (compared to your 48 seconds using AWK on a 2GB file)

Comment: Ah, OK  - sorry I was dense. Since you have made so much progress, maybe you should  post your answer: it would be interesting to see the Emacs implementation  you came up with. And having that and the data in a "permanent" answer, rather than in a comment, would be helpful in the future - IMO.

Comment: @NickD: for me, under real-world constraints, it has not been feasible to master `awk`, `perl`, `sed` and so forth. It is more practical to learn one tool well. Emacs is slower - but as shown repeatedly in these answers, it can do it all, and more intuitively. You're right: questions about `awk` belong elsewhere. But I did not ask about `awk`. I have appreciated your help. But are you entitled to tell people not to ask questions about Emacs in an Emacs forum?

Comment: @NickD: I should add: it is not true that users can confidently venture into Stack Exchange forums and ask people to write code for them. I have been dinged, in some such forums, for even daring to ask where to begin, without any request for specific code. The problem is not as you say. It is a matter of learning an entire foreign language in order to ask a simple question. I am here because I have had the experience of using Emacs for a variety of tasks, and I want to relearn that. That seems perfectly appropriate.

Comment: [Let's move the discussion to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/142161/discussion-with-ray-woodcock?tab=general)